# spring-boot RabbitHealthIndicator returns healthy on shutdown rabbitmq connections

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, kubernetes-health-check, health-check

We are using the default spring boot health checks - also for monitoring rabbitmq.

Unfortunately this doesn't work reliable. For example we have this in the log file:

```
2021-02-16 06:49:30.142 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.clos
e>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.143 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.clos
e>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.148 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] WARN  c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler  - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connecti
on reset)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.207 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.clos
e>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.208 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.clos
e>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.208 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.clos
e>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.209 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.clos
e>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
2021-02-16 06:49:30.209 [AMQP Connection 10.160.98.21:5672] WARN  c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler  - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connecti
on reset)
2021-02-16 06:49:33.736 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] WARN  o.s.b.a.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator  - Rabbit health check failed
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2089)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2062)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2042)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:44)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
....
2021-02-16 06:49:35.433 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-3] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Consumer raised exception, processin
g can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection ref
used)
2021-02-16 06:49:35.746 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-4] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Consumer raised exception, processin
g can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection ref
used)
2021-02-16 06:49:45.916 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] WARN  o.s.b.a.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator  - Rabbit health check failed
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)

...
2021-02-16 06:49:55.993 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-5] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer  - Failed to declare queue: pubxFileUploadQueue
2021-02-16 06:49:55.994 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-5] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer  - Queue declaration failed; retries left=1
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[pubxFileUploadQueue]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:700)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.passiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:584)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:571)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:1012)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1184)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:679)
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbit-rabbi
tmq-ha-0.rabbit-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.management.svc.cluster.local' of durable queue 'pubxFileUploadQueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbit-rabbi
tmq-ha-0.rabbit-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.management.svc.cluster.local' of durable queue 'pubxFileUploadQueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:517)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:341)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:739)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666)
        ... 1 common frames omitted

...
2021-02-16 06:50:01.012 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-6] ERROR o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Consumer threw missing queues except
ion, fatal=true
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.handleDeclarationException(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:651)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.passiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:591)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:571)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[pubxFileUploadQueue]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:700)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.passiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:584)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:1012)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1184)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:679)
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbit-rabbi
tmq-ha-0.rabbit-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.management.svc.cluster.local' of durable queue 'pubxFileUploadQueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbit-rabbi
tmq-ha-0.rabbit-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.management.svc.cluster.local' of durable queue 'pubxFileUploadQueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:517)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:341)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:739)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
2021-02-16 06:50:01.014 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-6] ERROR o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Stopping container from aborted cons
umer
```

But even a day later the health check is returning

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 48393486336,
        "free": 39704743936,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "livenessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "rabbit": {
      "status": "UP",
      "components": {
        "amqpAvailabilityTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "amqpDdcTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "amqpOesbTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "amqpRankingTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "amqpSiglTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "amqpTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "cflAmqpTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        },
        "rabbitTemplate": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "3.8.11"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "readinessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "storage": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  },
  "groups": ["liveness", "readiness"]
}
```

Did I miss some configuration or do I need to implement the health check myself to catch these kind of problems?

In fact I expected the connection would be recovered when the rabbit was available again.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `RabbitTemplate` that you are using is having retry enabled ?
In such case, can you try overriding the Rabbit Health indicator and give it a template without retry -

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomRabbitHealthIndicatorOverride
        extends CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration<RabbitHealthIndicator, RabbitTemplate> {

    @Bean
    public HealthIndicator rabbitHealthIndicator(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return createHealthIndicator(new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory));
    }

}
```